# Fetching data streams from facebook authentication.

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Hi I am designing a mobile app where users can login via facebook. The reason I use facebook login is because I can use facebook to reach out the users friends.

I would like to know is it possible to fetch the user email, friends email, address etc.... using a android app ?

If I can do that I can mass distribute my game.The posts on stack overflow regarding this topic is all on web app. However, I haven't seen any mobile game doing that, it seems most games uses PC version. They fetch those information using the web app not directly through the mobile app itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android SDK provided by Facebook.
Graph api provides whatever you need https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/.

There are many apps using this technique.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/bestpractice
They update user status for advertisement.

Comment: Thank you very much! First time using this site, my friend refer me to it. The response was instant and to the point.

Comment: @user3610701 Please mark this response as answer if this helped.